# how to interact with Silverlight VBA

Tags: vba, excel, silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I'm having a hard time making an application for automation using VBA, I can login to the site and access virtually every part of the site, but at some point I run into Silverlight, I can not access the objects inside it, Does anyone know how to do this?

Below the code snippet.

```
<object width="756" height"768" id="Silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2">
     <param name="source" value="/ClientBin/VisualizadorTif.xap"></param>
     <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError"></param>
     <param name="background" value="white"></param>
     <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0"></param>
     <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true"></param>
     <param name="windowless" value="true"></param>
     <param name="initParams" value="TipoImagem=,IdContrato=41f37130-588b-4907-adb4-2578b0391f35,NumeroPagina=0"></param>
     <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0">
          <img style="" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181"></img>
     </a>
</object>
```

Comment: Hello Luuklag, this is not duplicate, in this case you have localized is referring to Silverlight 3 mine is SL2, are different cases, and in case he has not had a solution if you look at the comments. He finished the subject without finding a solution.

Comment: I doubt the answer will change. Therefore it is most likely duplicate. We'll see what other have to say about it.